# using multiple instances of shared memory at once

Tags: c++, boost, ipc

to transport a video-stream between the recording program and the display program (which cannot be the same) I use shared memory.
To synch the access I've put together a class, which wraps a shared_memory_object, a mapped_region and an interprocess_sharable_mutex (all of boost::interprocess)

I wrote 2 construtors, one for the "Host"-side, and one for the "Client"-side.
When I use my class to transport one video-stream it works perfectly.
But when I try to transport two video streams there are a few problems.

First off: here is the constructor code:
(first one is the Host-Constructor, 2nd one the Client one)

```
    template<typename T>
    SWMRSharedMemArray<T>::SWMRSharedMemArray(std::string Name, size_t length):
        ShMutexSize(sizeof(interprocess_sharable_mutex)),
        isManager(true), _length(length), Name(Name)
    {
        shared_memory_object::remove(Name.c_str());

        shm = new shared_memory_object(create_only, Name.c_str(), read_write);
        shm->truncate(ShMutexSize + sizeof(T)*length);

        region = new mapped_region(*shm, read_write);

        void *addr = region->get_address();
        mtx = new(addr) interprocess_sharable_mutex;
        DataPtr = static_cast<T*>(addr) + ShMutexSize;
    }

    template<typename T>
    SWMRSharedMemArray<T>::SWMRSharedMemArray(std::string Name) :
        ShMutexSize(sizeof(interprocess_sharable_mutex)),
        isManager(false), Name(Name)
    {
        shm = new shared_memory_object(open_only, Name.c_str(), read_write);
        region = new mapped_region(*shm, read_write);

        _length = (region->get_size() - ShMutexSize) / sizeof(T);
        void *addr = region->get_address();
        mtx = static_cast<decltype(mtx)>(addr);
        DataPtr = static_cast<T*>(addr) + ShMutexSize;
    }
```

On the Host-Side everything still looks fine.
But on the construction for the Clients there are problems:
When I compare the shm and region objects of the first and seccond instance
(which have different Names ofc, but same length, and template-type)
I see that a lot of members that should differ do not.
The adress and the member m_filename are different as expected, but the member m_handle is the same.
For region the both adresses are different, but all members are identical.

I hope someone knows whats going on.
Best Regards
Uzaku

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not completely grokked your code, but I was struck by the archaic use of manual memory management. Whenever I see "sizeof()" in C++ I get slightly worried :)

Confusion is almost inevitable due to the lack of abstraction, and the compiler is unable to help, because you're in "Leave Me Alone - I Know What I'm Doing" land.

Concretely, **this looks wrong:**

```
DataPtr = static_cast<T *>(addr) + ShMutexSize;
```

This might be correct when `sizeof(T)==sizeof(char)` (IOW, `T` is a byte), but otherwise you get *pointer arithmetic*, meaning that you add `sizeof(T)` `ShMutexSize` times. This is definitely wrong, because you only reserved room for the size of the mutex+the element data, directly adjacent.

So you get unused space and [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to indexing beyond the size of the shared memory region.

---

So, let me contrast with two samples;

1. that reduces the dependence on pointer arithmetic
2. that does away with all the manual memory management by using managed shared memory segments

#### 1. Manual

The manual approach that doesn't quite require the same amount of pointer trickery/resource management could look like this:

**<kbd>[<strike>Live</strike>Compiled On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79a26cf808ea8dd6)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_sharable_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

namespace SWMR {
    static struct server_mode_t {} const/*expr*/ server_mode = server_mode_t();
    static struct client_mode_t {} const/*expr*/ client_mode = client_mode_t();

    typedef bip::interprocess_sharable_mutex mutex;
    typedef boost::lock_guard<mutex> guard;

    template <typename T, size_t N> struct SharedMemArray {
        SharedMemArray(server_mode_t, std::string const& name) 
          : isManager(true), _name(name), 
            _shm(do_create(_name.c_str())),
            _region(_shm, bip::read_write)
        {
            _data = new (_region.get_address()) data_t;
        }

        SharedMemArray(client_mode_t, std::string const& name) 
          : isManager(false), _name(name),
            _shm(do_open(_name.c_str())),
            _region(_shm, bip::read_write),
            _data(static_cast<data_t*>(_region.get_address()))
        {
            assert(sizeof(data_t) == _region.get_size());
        }

    private:
        typedef bip::shared_memory_object shm_t;
        struct data_t { 
            mutable mutex mtx;
            T DataPtr[N];
        };

        bool               isManager;
        const std::string  _name;
        shm_t              _shm;
        bip::mapped_region _region;
        data_t            *_data;

        // functions to manage the shared memory
        shm_t static do_create(char const* name) {
            shm_t::remove(name);
            shm_t result(bip::create_only, name, bip::read_write);
            result.truncate(sizeof(data_t));
            return boost::move(result);
        }

        shm_t static do_open(char const* name) {
            return shm_t(bip::open_only, name, bip::read_write);
        }

      public:
        mutex& get_mutex() const { return _data->mtx; }

        typedef T       *iterator;
        typedef T const *const_iterator;

        iterator data()                { return _data->DataPtr; }
        const_iterator data() const    { return _data->DataPtr; }

        iterator begin()               { return data(); }
        const_iterator begin() const   { return data(); }

        iterator end()                 { return begin() + N; }
        const_iterator end() const     { return begin() + N; }

        const_iterator cbegin() const  { return begin(); }
        const_iterator cend() const    { return end(); }
    };
}

#include <vector>

static const std::string APP_UUID = "61ab4f43-2d68-46e1-9c8d-31d577ce3aa7";

struct UserData {
    int   i;
    float f;
};

#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace SWMR;
    SharedMemArray<int, 20>      s_ints   (server_mode, APP_UUID + "-ints");
    SharedMemArray<float, 72>    s_floats (server_mode, APP_UUID + "-floats");
    SharedMemArray<UserData, 10> s_udts   (server_mode, APP_UUID + "-udts");

    {
        guard lk(s_ints.get_mutex());
        boost::fill(s_ints, 42);
    }

    {
        guard lk(s_floats.get_mutex());
        boost::fill(s_floats, 31415);
    }

    {
        guard lk(s_udts.get_mutex());
        UserData udt = { 42, 3.14 };
        boost::fill(s_udts, udt);
    }

    SharedMemArray<int, 20>      c_ints   (client_mode, APP_UUID + "-ints");
    SharedMemArray<float, 72>    c_floats (client_mode, APP_UUID + "-floats");
    SharedMemArray<UserData, 10> c_udts   (client_mode, APP_UUID + "-udts");

    {
        guard lk(c_ints.get_mutex());
        assert(boost::equal(std::vector<int>(boost::size(c_ints), 42), c_ints));
    }

    {
        guard lk(c_floats.get_mutex());
        assert(boost::equal(std::vector<int>(boost::size(c_floats), 31415), c_floats));
    }

    {
        guard lk(c_udts.get_mutex());
        BOOST_FOREACH(UserData& udt, c_udts)
            std::cout << udt.i << "\t" << udt.f << "\n";
    }
}
```

Notes

- it reuses code
- it doesn't do unnecessary dynamic allocations (which makes the class much easier to "get right" for Rule Of Three)
- it uses a `data_t` struct to get rid of the manual offset calculations (you can just do `data->mtx` or `data->DataPtr`)
- it adds `iterator` and `begin()`/`end()` definitions so that you can use the `SharedMemArray` directly as a range, e.g. with algorithms like `boost::equal` and `BOOST_FOREACH`:

  ```
  assert(boost::equal(some_vector, c_floats));

  BOOST_FOREACH(UserData& udt, c_udts)
      std::cout << udt.i << "\t" << udt.f << "\n";
  ```
- for now, it uses a statically known number of elements (`N`).

If you don't want this, I'd *certainly* opt for the approach that uses *managed segments* (under 2.) because that will take care of all the (re)allocation mechanics for you.

---

#### 2. Using a `managed_shared_memory` segment

What do we use in C++ when we want dynamically sized arrays? *Correct:* `std::vector`.

Now `std::vector` can be taught to allocate from the shared memory, but you'll need to pass it an Boost Interprocess `allocator`. This allocator knows how to work with a `segment_manager` to perform the allocations from shared memory.

Here's a relatively straight up translation to using `managed_shared_memory`

**<kbd>[<strike>Live</strike>Compiled On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98be67dee8787659)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>

#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>

#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_sharable_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp>

namespace Shared {
    namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
    namespace bc  = boost::container;

    using shm_t = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using mutex = bip::interprocess_sharable_mutex;
    using guard = boost::lock_guard<mutex>;

    template <typename T> using allocator    = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<
                                                   bip::allocator<T, shm_t::segment_manager>
                                               >;
    template <typename T> using vector       = bc::vector<T, allocator<T> >;
    template <typename T> using basic_string = bc::basic_string<T, std::char_traits<T>, allocator<T> >;

    using string  = basic_string<char>;
    using wstring = basic_string<wchar_t>;
}

namespace SWMR {
    namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

    static struct server_mode_t {} const/*expr*/ server_mode = server_mode_t();
    static struct client_mode_t {} const/*expr*/ client_mode = client_mode_t();

    template <typename T> struct SharedMemArray {

    private:
        struct data_t {
            using allocator_type = Shared::allocator<void>;

            data_t(size_t N, allocator_type alloc) : elements(alloc) { elements.resize(N); }
            data_t(allocator_type alloc)           : elements(alloc) {}

            mutable Shared::mutex mtx;
            Shared::vector<T> elements;
        };

        bool               isManager;
        const std::string  _name;
        Shared::shm_t      _shm;
        data_t            *_data;

        // functions to manage the shared memory
        Shared::shm_t static do_create(char const* name) {
            bip::shared_memory_object::remove(name);
            Shared::shm_t result(bip::create_only, name, 1ul << 20); // ~1 MiB
            return boost::move(result);
        }

        Shared::shm_t static do_open(char const* name) {
            return Shared::shm_t(bip::open_only, name);
        }

      public:
        SharedMemArray(server_mode_t, std::string const& name, size_t N = 0)
          : isManager(true), _name(name), _shm(do_create(_name.c_str()))
        {
            _data = _shm.find_or_construct<data_t>(name.c_str())(N, _shm.get_segment_manager());
        }

        SharedMemArray(client_mode_t, std::string const& name)
          : isManager(false), _name(name), _shm(do_open(_name.c_str()))
        {
            auto found = _shm.find<data_t>(name.c_str());
            assert(found.second);
            _data = found.first;
        }

        Shared::mutex&  mutex() const             { return _data->mtx; }
        Shared::vector<T>      & elements()       { return _data->elements; }
        Shared::vector<T> const& elements() const { return _data->elements; }
    };
}

#include <vector>

static const std::string APP_UUID = "93f6b721-1d34-46d9-9877-f967fea61cf2";

struct UserData {
    using allocator_type = Shared::allocator<void>;

    UserData(allocator_type alloc) : text(alloc) {}
    UserData(UserData const& other, allocator_type alloc) : i(other.i), text(other.text, alloc) {}
    UserData(int i, Shared::string t) : i(i), text(t) {}
    template <typename T> UserData(int i, T&& t, allocator_type alloc) : i(i), text(std::forward<T>(t), alloc) {}

    // data
    int   i;
    Shared::string text;
};

#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace SWMR;
    SharedMemArray<int>      s_ints(server_mode, APP_UUID + "-ints", 20);
    SharedMemArray<UserData> s_udts(server_mode, APP_UUID + "-udts");
    // server code

    {
        Shared::guard lk(s_ints.mutex());
        boost::fill(s_ints.elements(), 99);

        // or manipulate the vector. Any allocations go to the shared memory segment automatically
        s_ints.elements().push_back(42);
        s_ints.elements().assign(20, 42);
    }

    {
        Shared::guard lk(s_udts.mutex());
        s_udts.elements().emplace_back(1, "one");
    }

    // client code
    SharedMemArray<int>      c_ints(client_mode, APP_UUID + "-ints");
    SharedMemArray<UserData> c_udts(client_mode, APP_UUID + "-udts");

    {
        Shared::guard lk(c_ints.mutex());
        auto& e = c_ints.elements();
        assert(boost::equal(std::vector<int>(20, 42), e));
    }

    {
        Shared::guard lk(c_udts.mutex());
        BOOST_FOREACH(UserData& udt, c_udts.elements())
            std::cout << udt.i << "\t'" << udt.text << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Since you're now storing first class C++ objects, the sizes are not static. In fact, you can `push_back` and if the capacity is exceeded, the container will just reallocate from using the segment's allocator.
- I've elected to use C++11 for the convenience typedefs in `namespace Shared`. However, all of these can work in c++03, though with more verbosity
- I've also elected to use *scoped allocators* through out. This means that if `T` is a (user-defined) type that /also/ uses an allocator (e.g. [all standard containers, `std::deque`, `std::packaged_task`, `std::tuple` etc.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator) the allocator's segment reference will be implicitly passed to the elements when they're internally constructed. This is e.g. why the lines

  ```
  elements.resize(N);
  ```

  and

  ```
  s_udts.elements().emplace_back(1, "one");
  ```

  are able to compile without explicitly passing an allocator for the element's constructor.
- The sample `UserData` class exploits this to show how you can contain a `std::string` (or actually, a `Shared::string`) which *magically* allocates from the same memory segment as the container.

#### 3. Bonus

Note also that this opens up the possibility to store all the containers inside a single `shared_memory_object` this may be beneficial, and therefore I present a variation that shows this approach:

**<kbd>[<strike>Live</strike>Compiled On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbf56632dea1b069)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>

#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>

#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/offset_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_sharable_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp>

namespace Shared {
    namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
    namespace bc  = boost::container;

    using msm_t = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using mutex = bip::interprocess_sharable_mutex;
    using guard = boost::lock_guard<mutex>;

    template <typename T> using allocator    = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<
                                                   bip::allocator<T, msm_t::segment_manager>
                                               >;
    template <typename T> using vector       = bc::vector<T, allocator<T> >;
    template <typename T> using basic_string = bc::basic_string<T, std::char_traits<T>, allocator<T> >;

    using string  = basic_string<char>;
    using wstring = basic_string<wchar_t>;
}

namespace SWMR {
    namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
    namespace bc  = boost::container;

    class Segment {
      public:
        // LockableObject, base template
        //
        // LockableObject contains a `Shared::mutex` and an object of type T
        template <typename T, typename Enable = void> struct LockableObject;

        // Partial specialization for the case when the wrapped object cannot
        // use the shared allocator: the constructor is just forwarded
        template <typename T>
        struct LockableObject<T, typename boost::disable_if<bc::uses_allocator<T, Shared::allocator<T> >, void>::type>
        {
            template <typename... CtorArgs>
            LockableObject(CtorArgs&&... args) : object(std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...) {}
            LockableObject() : object() {}

            mutable Shared::mutex mutex;
            T object;

          private:
            friend class Segment;
            template <typename... CtorArgs>
            static LockableObject& locate_by_name(Shared::msm_t& msm, const char* tag, CtorArgs&&... args) {
                return *msm.find_or_construct<LockableObject<T> >(tag)(std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...);
            }
        };

        // Partial specialization for the case where the contained object can
        // use the shared allocator;
        //
        // Construction (using locate_by_name) adds the allocator as the last
        // argument.
        template <typename T>
        struct LockableObject<T, typename boost::enable_if<bc::uses_allocator<T, Shared::allocator<T> >, void>::type>
        {
            using allocator_type = Shared::allocator<void>;

            template <typename... CtorArgs>
            LockableObject(CtorArgs&&... args) : object(std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...) {}
            LockableObject(allocator_type alloc = {}) : object(alloc) {}

            mutable Shared::mutex mutex;
            T object;

          private:
            friend class Segment;
            template <typename... CtorArgs>
            static LockableObject& locate_by_name(Shared::msm_t& msm, const char* tag, CtorArgs&&... args) {
                return *msm.find_or_construct<LockableObject>(tag)(std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)..., Shared::allocator<T>(msm.get_segment_manager()));
            }
        };

        Segment(std::string const& name, size_t capacity = 1024*1024) // default 1 MiB
            : _msm(bip::open_or_create, name.c_str(), capacity)
        {
        }

        template <typename T, typename... CtorArgs>
        LockableObject<T>& getLockable(char const* tag, CtorArgs&&... args) {
            return LockableObject<T>::locate_by_name(_msm, tag, std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...);
        }

    private:
        Shared::msm_t _msm;
    };
}

#include <vector>

static char const* const APP_UUID = "249f3878-3ddf-4473-84b2-755998952da1";

struct UserData {
    using allocator_type = Shared::allocator<void>;
    using String         = Shared::string;

    UserData(allocator_type alloc) : text(alloc) { }
    UserData(int i, String t) : i(i), text(t) { }
    UserData(UserData const& other, allocator_type alloc) : i(other.i), text(other.text, alloc) { }

    template <typename T>
        UserData(int i, T&& t, allocator_type alloc)
            : i(i), text(std::forward<T>(t), alloc)
        { }

    // data
    int i;
    String text;
};

#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using IntVec = Shared::vector<int>;
    using UdtVec = Shared::vector<UserData>;

    boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(APP_UUID); // for demo

    // server code
    {
        SWMR::Segment server(APP_UUID);

        auto& s_ints = server.getLockable<IntVec>("ints", std::initializer_list<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,42}); // allocator automatically added
        auto& s_udts = server.getLockable<UdtVec>("udts");

        {
            Shared::guard lk(s_ints.mutex);
            boost::fill(s_ints.object, 99);

            // or manipulate the vector. Any allocations go to the shared memory segment automatically
            s_ints.object.push_back(42);
            s_ints.object.assign(20, 42);
        }

        {
            Shared::guard lk(s_udts.mutex);
            s_udts.object.emplace_back(1, "one"); // allocates the string in shared memory, and the UserData element too
        }
    }

    // client code
    {
        SWMR::Segment client(APP_UUID);

        auto& c_ints = client.getLockable<IntVec>("ints", 20, 999); // the ctor arguments are ignored here
        auto& c_udts = client.getLockable<UdtVec>("udts");

        {
            Shared::guard lk(c_ints.mutex);
            IntVec& ivec = c_ints.object;
            assert(boost::equal(std::vector<int>(20, 42), ivec));
        }

        {
            Shared::guard lk(c_udts.mutex);
            BOOST_FOREACH(UserData& udt, c_udts.object)
                std::cout << udt.i << "\t'" << udt.text << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- you can now store anything, not just "dynamic arrays" (`vector<T>`). You could just do:

  ```
  auto& c_udts = client.getLockable<double>("a_single_double");
  ```
- when you store a container that is compatible with the shared allocator, `LockableObject`'s construction method will transparently add the allocator instance as the last constructor argument for the contained `T object;`.
- I moved the `remove()` call out of the `Segment` class, making it unnecessary to distinguish between client/server mode. We just use `open_or_create` and `find_or_construct`.

Comment: @BenVoigt What are you referring to? The currently shown code _doesn't_ use it yet (as is plain to see)

Comment: @sehe: The last heading could be useful advice, if it were clear what `managed_shared_memory` class could be used to solve the problem.  Of course it will be even more useful with the complete example.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm writing that

Comment: Added the `managed_shared_memory` variation - which is much more flexible, and actually a bonus variation of that (that combines all the shared allocations under a single `shared_memory_object` for cleanness. I hope this serves as inspiration on using Boost Interprocess's more highlevel interfaces. /cc @BenVoigt

Comment: @sehe : I know its after 2 years. In your option 1 implementation code - how do we synchronize if client and server can start at any time. Before the server does placement `new` the client could access the location right? [I have a similar situation, and was thinking how I can resolve the situation?]